# Resize the tableview statically in ios

Tags: ios

I set the Tableview in .xib file.now i need resize the tableview in xib.i resized this table view in .xib file.but,not worked.and set the code in programmatically.always not worked.

Comment: If it didn't work, what did it do? Is this for iPad or iPhone? What does your code look like? More context is needed.

Comment: i don't know how to resize the tableview .xib file.it is a iPhone. This is my code.  friendListView.frame=(CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300));

Answer (score 0):

Remove "use autolayout" checkmark in the interface builder first. It is in file inspector tab when you select the tableview